# Rails server - Port problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hosting

I'm trying to launch a rails server on the shared hosting I just bought, but I've got some little problems.

1- I can't launch `rails server` on port 90. I get an error.

> /opt/alt/ruby21/lib64/ruby/2.1.0/socket.rb:206:in `bind': Permission
>   denied - bind(2) for 67.205.125.31:90 (Errno::EACCES)
>    from /opt/alt/ruby21/lib64/ruby/2.1.0/socket.rb:206:in`listen'
>           from /opt/alt/ruby21/lib64/ruby/2.1.0/socket.rb:461:in `block in tcp_server_sockets'
>           from /opt/alt/ruby21/lib64/ruby/2.1.0/socket.rb:232:in`each'
>           from /opt/alt/ruby21/lib64/ruby/2.1.0/socket.rb:232:in `foreach'
>           from /opt/alt/ruby21/lib64/ruby/2.1.0/socket.rb:459:in`tcp_server_sockets'
>           from /opt/alt/ruby21/lib64/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/utils.rb:75:in `create_listeners'
>           from /opt/alt/ruby21/lib64/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:132:in`listen'
>           from /opt/alt/ruby21/lib64/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:113:in `initialize'
>           from /opt/alt/ruby21/lib64/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:45:in`initialize'
>           from /home/tmtcmon/rubyvenv/App/2.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:31:in `new'
>           from /home/tmtcmon/rubyvenv/App/2.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:31:in`run'
>           from /home/tmtcmon/rubyvenv/App/2.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:286:in `start'
>           from /home/tmtcmon/rubyvenv/App/2.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in`start'
>           from /home/tmtcmon/rubyvenv/App/2.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
>           from /home/tmtcmon/rubyvenv/App/2.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in`tap'
>           from /home/tmtcmon/rubyvenv/App/2.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
>           from /home/tmtcmon/rubyvenv/App/2.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in`run_command!'
>           from /home/tmtcmon/rubyvenv/App/2.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
>           from bin/rails:4:in`require'
>           from bin/rails:4:in `'

Could this error be cause by the fact I'm on a shared hosting, therefore I couldn't launch something on port 90 because it is already used ?

2- I can't launch `rails server` on port 3000. (the default port). This time I can launch my server, but can't acces it with `http//:domain-name.com:3000`

3- If I launch `rails server` on a random port, (I tried 30,000) the server works perfectly. The problem is http://domain-name.com:30000 doesn't look real good and I'd prefer only http//:domain-name.com

So, with those three problems, three questions :

1- Is it possible to launch my server on port 90 even if I have shared hosting ? If so, do you have an idea what did I did wrong ?

2- Why can't I launch effectivly on port 3000 ? (this one isn't really a problem because I'd prefer the server to launch on port 90, but I'm curious.

3- Is it a way to redirect all my traffic on port 30,000 **without http//:domain-name:30000 being showed in the adress bar** ? I've managed to do that with .htacces, the user can connect by typing http//:domain-name but it shows http://domain-name:30000 in the adress bar...

Thanks in advance !

EDIT : Sorry if the question as already been answered, but if so, I couldn't find it after hours of research...

Answer (score 2):

You cannot bind to port 90 or anything less than 1024 if you are not root, and probably someone else is running a service on port 3000 already, you can do a `netstat -nat | grep 3000` to see if there is any process is listening.

Comment: I get a "command not found" when I try to run netstat. I guess my host doesn't let me run some commands, (?) but it's totally possible someone else is running something on port 3000. I didn't know a non-root couldn't launch a process on port <1024... Thanks !

Comment: you can try `curl http://localhost:3000` or `telnet localhost 3000` or `wget -O - http://localhost:3000`, there should be a command that you can use to test connection.

Comment: curl http://localhost:3000 kind of confirms there i no process on port 3000. (It gets me a page of my host saying I've trie to acces a page that doesn't exists.)

Comment: If `curl` returns anything (even 404) other than error then it means there is something running, you can do `curl -v` to see the response header. Pity it's hard to tell who's running it in a shared hosting environment.

Comment: `* About to connect() to localhost port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET /:300000 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.19.1 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
> Host: localhost
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Date: Sat, 26 Mar 2016 02:15:23 GMT
< Server: Apache
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/html
<
` Is it what you were looking for ? ^^

Comment: What did you run? It seems to connect to port 80 instead of 3000. The full command is `curl -v http://localhost:3000/`

Comment: `curl localhost/:3000 -v`

Comment: Wrong one, it should be `localhost:3000/` instead of `localhost/:3000`

Comment: With the good command this time :p `* About to connect() to localhost port 3000 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... Connection refused
*   Trying ::1... Failed to connect to ::1: Network is unreachable
* Success
* couldn't connect to host
* Closing connection #0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to ::1: Network is unreachable`

Comment: Then it means nothing's running on port 3000 and you should be able to run it, if may be VPS provider's firewall rule that disallow the connection from outside to this server's port 3000, but again under a VPS environment, this is hard to tell, maybe asking tech support guy to give an explanation?

Comment: I'll try that ! Thanks a lot for your helpful help ! :)